# stopPropagation not working on draggable resizble div

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, resizable, stoppropagation

I have a div which is draggable and resizable.

On double click I want to use stopPropagation to make the contents of the div to be selectable.

But for some reason the stopPropagation is not working.

can anybody please have a look at my code and see where I am going wrong?

heres a jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/j6FLa/16/

and the code

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src= "http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
<style>
 .dragbox {
 position:absolute;
 width:10px;
 height:25px;
 padding: 0.0em;
 margin:25px;
 cursor:move;
 z-index:2
 }
</style>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<script>
//<![CDATA[
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
    var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
    myNicEditor.setPanel('myNicPanel');
    myNicEditor.addInstance('draggable');
});
//]]>


$("div.dragbox").dblclick(function (e) {
    $('.dragbox').css('cursor','select');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable().resizable();
});
</script>
<div id="myNicPanel" style="width: 525px;"></div>
<div id="draggable" class="dragbox" style="width:300px;height:300px;background-color:#ff0000;padding:25px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed magna dolor</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: my inblox says I have 3 comments on this question but they are not showing on the page...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a kind of workaround:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j6FLa/17/)

```
$("div.dragbox").dblclick(function (e) {
    $('.dragbox').css('cursor','select');
    $(this).draggable( 'disable' ).removeClass('ui-state-disabled').focus();
}).on('blur',function(){
    $(this).draggable( 'enable' );
});
```

Or better:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j6FLa/18/)

```
$("div.dragbox").dblclick(function (e) {
    if(!$(this).data('editing')){
    $('.dragbox').css('cursor','select');
    $(this).draggable( 'disable' ).removeClass('ui-state-disabled').focus();
        $(this).data('editing',true);
    }
    else {
        $(this).data('editing',false);
         $(this).draggable( 'enable' )
    }
});
```

Comment: that seems to wwork on the fiddle Ill try it on my webserver...cheers

Comment: have you clear cache, no reason it works in jsfiddle but not on your server

Comment: yeah I also tried in all browsers that I had not even used today

Comment: provide a link to test it online, you are doing something wrong i think

Comment: you need to wrap snippet with DOM ready handler: `$(function(){...});`  and then it works

Comment: what is the code for that and where would it go, sorry my javascript is not the best